# In React with ES6 , constructor(prop) doesn't raise error. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The correct code that i found everywhere was as follows:

```
class App extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      //more code...
   }
}
```

but i was mistyping `props` as `prop`. Still the code worked fine and no errors were raised. I couldn't find why it was so though.

Comment: The name of the variable is not important and it just is there to give you the developer an idea of what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor is a javascript function. The arguments that it takes are positional arguments. That means the values are determined by their position in the argument list and not by their name. Javascript doesn't have named parameters.

The first parameter of the `constructor` of `React.Component` is containing the props that where passed to it on creation (The second one is the context). It doesn't matter which name you use for the parameter inside your implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is a function, and:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
```

is the declaration of the `function`. So, the name of the variable passed to `constructor()` as parameter just makes difference inside of it. You can pass any information as a `parameter`, and it will deal with it.

You could define your `constructor()` as:

```
constructor(foo) {
    super(foo)
}
```

And it would work just like the standart definition.

The both calls of `constructor()` below work on the same way, don't matter what you pass as `parameter`.

```
constructor('Foo')
constructor({ bar: 'Bar', foo: 'Foo'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is local to the scope of `constructor()` so it doesn't matter what you call it.

Answer (score 0):

`constructor` is a function in javascript. Passing `props` to constructor is like passing a variable to a function. It is similar to how you write a function

```
let foo = ( bar ) => bar*bar
```

and you can call the function like

```
foo(someOtherVariable)
```

and don't have to do `foo(bar)` itself

Answer (score 0):

The parameter and argument name do not have to be the same. Therefore although you are passing in props you can call it "myPassedVariables", "prop" or anything else you think is suitable. I would however use Typescript which shortens the whole path from:

```
class Person {
    private firstName: string;
    private lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

To:

```
class Person {
    constructor(private firstName: string, private lastName: string) {
    }
}
```

Shorter and auto instantiates without rewriting each variable individually like many other languages.